# using spring boot dev tool in msf4j and netbeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netbeans, msf4j

am using `msf4j-spring` and am trying to use the `spring-boot-devtools` for hot Reloading and restarting. My IDE is netbeans and I have set my IDE to compile on save, yet when I edit my `.java` files and `properties` files it does not restart or reload my `micro-service` application. Below is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>org.wso2.msf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>msf4j-service</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <relativePath>parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.innovectives.integration.nibss.outbound</groupId>
<artifactId>innovectives-nibss-outbound</artifactId>
<name>Innovectives Outbound Microservice</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.msf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>msf4j-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.innovectives.octopus</groupId>
        <artifactId>octopus-ssm-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <optional>false</optional>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <microservice.mainClass>com.innovectives.nibss.Application</microservice.mainClass>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.innovectives.nibss.Application</mainClass>
                <layout>JAR</layout>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How are you launching you application? And which documentation states that *spring-dev-tools* support *msf4j*?

Comment: @tmarwen I launch my application with `netbeans` Play button whihc starts the `main application class`